# How do I fix missing bar from seaborn bar plot after changing the name of ticks?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a barplot with seaborn and I want to change the labels of the xticks.
When the ticks remain numbers all the bars show on the graph. To get these numbers I created a column with the month of each sale date and used grouby to group the data by the month.

```py
pr_sales = sns.barplot(x='Month', y='dollartotal', color='lightblue', data=df_pr_2020,   )
pr_sales.set(xlabel='2020 by Month', ylabel='Dollars', title='2020 Pre-Roll Sales ')
```

See below X axis numbers:

[image: img]

But when I convert the axis to labels I lose a bar of data. The main difference in this code is Months are taken from the `saledate` column.

```py
pr_sales = sns.barplot(x='Month', y='dollartotal', color='lightblue', data=df_pr_2020,   )
    
pr_sales.set(xlabel='2020 by Month', ylabel='Dollars', title='2020 Pre-Roll Sales ')
pr_sales.set_xticks(range(len(Months)))
    
pr_sales.set_xticklabels(Months)
    
Months =df_pr_2020['saledate'].dt.strftime('%b')
```

As you can see December is now showing:
[image: img2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original dataframe, data for april are missing, so when you change tik labels, ticks shift to the left, and it seems december is empty.
I suppose you are working with a dataframe like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


samples = 10
df_pr_2020 = pd.DataFrame({'date': np.repeat(pd.date_range(start = '2020-01-01', end = '2020-12-31', freq = 'D'), samples)})
df_pr_2020 = df_pr_2020[df_pr_2020['date'].dt.month != 4]
df_pr_2020['dollartotal'] = 14000*df_pr_2020['date'].dt.month + 150000 + 20000*np.random.randn(len(df_pr_2020))
df_pr_2020['Month'] = df_pr_2020['date'].dt.month.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.zfill(2))
```

```
           date    dollartotal Month
0    2020-01-01  176160.921650    01
1    2020-01-01  166157.143534    01
2    2020-01-01  187411.157138    01
3    2020-01-01  114761.306578    01
4    2020-01-01  164297.114934    01
5    2020-01-01  163810.407586    01
6    2020-01-01  133359.064046    01
7    2020-01-01  151415.390232    01
8    2020-01-01  131282.857219    01
9    2020-01-01  155171.540172    01
10   2020-01-02  189664.518915    01
11   2020-01-02  156596.250250    01
12   2020-01-02  148865.016156    01
13   2020-01-02  173507.621407    01
14   2020-01-02  155717.433085    01
15   2020-01-02  166862.159482    01
```

When plotting you get (notice missing april):

[image]

When you extract `'Month'` column, you could already convert it from month number to month short name:

```
df_pr_2020['Month'] = df_pr_2020['date'].dt.month_name().str[:3]
```

### Complete Code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


samples = 10
df_pr_2020 = pd.DataFrame({'date': np.repeat(pd.date_range(start = '2020-01-01', end = '2020-12-31', freq = 'D'), samples)})
df_pr_2020 = df_pr_2020[df_pr_2020['date'].dt.month != 4]
df_pr_2020['dollartotal'] = 14000*df_pr_2020['date'].dt.month + 150000 + 20000*np.random.randn(len(df_pr_2020))
df_pr_2020['Month'] = df_pr_2020['date'].dt.month_name().str[:3]


pr_sales = sns.barplot(x='Month', y='dollartotal', color='lightblue', data=df_pr_2020)
pr_sales.set(xlabel='2020 by Month', ylabel='Dollars', title='2020 Pre-Roll Sales ')

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

As you can see, x ticks are converted in month short name and data for april are still missing, as per original data.

[image]

Comment: You can pass `df_pr_2020['date'].dt.month_name().str[:3]` straight to `x` if you don't want to modify the original dataframe.

Comment: @mwaskom in this case, `df_pr_2020.date.dt.strftime('%b')`